# Call of overloaded 'arg(QString (&)())' is ambiguous when called using QApplication::applicationDirPath, why?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

```
QString msgText = QString("The file has been saved at %1\sysconf.xml").arg(QApplication::applicationDirPath);
```

gives me the above error. I used `.arg()` before, so I wonder why it gives me this error? All my other `.arg()` in my code works properly.

Comment: Can you please provide the *complete* error message? It includes the actual types of the call, and often also the alternative functions available.

Comment: I think there's plenty enough of typo questions on SO. This one won't help anyone else, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**THE EXPLANATION**

`QApplication::applicationDirPath` is a static member function, to get the value you are looking for you must treat it as such, hence; you must call the function.

Currently you are trying to pass a *function pointer* to `QString::arg`, and since the compiler cannot find a suitable overload for such construct it raises a diagnostic.

---

**THE SOLUTION**

```
QString msgText = QString(...).arg(QApplication::applicationDirPath ());
```

<sup>**Note:** See the added `()` after `QApplication::applicationDirPath`.</sup>

Comment: Oh damn, right! Thanks for the explanation though. Now it works!

Comment: It seems to find more than one suitable overload, or elde the error message should be different. Wich makes me wonder what those overloads might be?

Answer (score 1):

Try actually calling the function:

```
QString msgText = QString("The file has been saved at %1\sysconf.xml").arg(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

Notice the *"()"* after applicationDirPath.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) you are passing a pointer to the static member function `applicationDirPath`, and `arg` has several overloads that all do *not* accept such a poitner. It seems your compiler finds several conversions of the function pointer to the parameter types `arg` is overloaded for and gets confused. Did you mean this:

```
QString msgText = QString("The file has been saved at %1\sysconf.xml")
  .arg(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
                                 //    ^^--!!
```